# OData Feed (not in my control) - Can I compress (gzip) or send it over JSON?

Tags: xml, json, web-services, compression

I am trying to consume an OData web-based web service that is XML (based on AtobPub protocol).  I don't have access to the server and thus cannot enabled compresssion (I know it is not set).  Some of the payloads are quite large.

I am wondering what one can do from a client-side developer's point-of-view, to better consume these services.  Manually compress and decompress the xml payloads?  How about JSON, is this possible?

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE (02/29/2012):** After one response so far, I would like to clarify that I am a consumer of these services and not the producer.  There is a strict restriction to the servers that these services and applications are hosted on and compression, unfortunately, is not set and thus the xml services come through non-gzipped (not compressed at all).  The servers are heterogeneous with Linux and Windows in the mix.  As a developer, creating the DAL, BLL, UI, etc., what can I do to make sure the Requests/Responses are compressed?  Implement by own GZip compression algorithm/function and decompression of XML messages?

Answer (score 0):

If the server supports it you should be able to request JSON. Typically by setting Accept header on your request to application/json. Or some servers even support adding $format=json to the URL for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks Vitek for your response, but I don't believe that helps in my case.  I noted that I do not have control of any of these servers.  Our service calls go through multiple servers, e.g. Linux and Windows.  Regarding my WCF Data Services, is there any way I can implement my own compression and forget about any server integration?  If so, where would be the best plugin points?  How about some bindings in the config files?

Comment: @user118190 this setting of `application/json` in your Accept header is not anything to do with the server, it's done on the client side. OData supports both Atom and Json by default, you just have to request it in your request header.

Comment: It's been a while since I posted anything to this, but was wondering about the first part of my question, i.e. the part about compressing the data (both sending/receiving).  I see many services coming in as gzip, but would like to know the details, thanks.